# unique_ptr and default constructible pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, unique-ptr

Recently I tried to reinvent *scope guard* via `std::unique_ptr` (**NOTE**: *Deleter* has the member typedef `pointer` — is a specially handled case of `std::unique_ptr`):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

namespace
{

template< typename lambda >
auto
make_scope_guard(lambda && _lambda)
{
    struct lambda_caller
    {

        using pointer = std::decay_t< lambda >;

        void
        operator () (lambda & l) const noexcept
        {
            std::forward< lambda >(l)();
        }

    };
    return std::unique_ptr< std::decay_t< lambda >, lambda_caller >(std::forward< lambda >(_lambda));
}

}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
        [[gnu::unused]] auto && guard_ = make_scope_guard([&] { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; });
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Such an approach works fine for simple pointer to free function `void f() { std::cout << 4 << std::endl; }` passed to `make_scope_guard`, but not for any lambda passed to `make_scope_guard`.

This is due to an abundance of `... = pointer()` into the `std::unique_ptr` definition (function default parameter, defaulting data memebers etc), but I can't find the *DefaultConstructible* requirement for `pointer` into this [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

Is it mandatory, that the `pointer` should match the `std::is_default_constructible` requirement?

It tested against `libc++` and against `libstdc++` using not too old `clang++ -std=gnu++1z`.

Seems, there should be language extension for lambdas: if `auto l = [/* possible capture list */] (Args...) { /* code */; };` then `using L = decltype(l);` is equivalent to `struct L { constexpr void operator () (Args...) const noexcept { ; } };` for some `Args...`, isn't it?

**ADDITIONAL:**

Providing the instance `D{}` of following *DefaultConstructible* class to `make_scope_guard(D{})` requires commented out code to be uncommented in the context `if (p) { ...`, where `p` is of type `D`:

```
struct D { void operator () () const noexcept { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; } /* constexpr operator bool () const { return true; } */ };
```

Answer (score 4):

A `unique_ptr` is still a pointer. You cannot shoehorn a lambda into it. From [unique.ptr]:

> A *unique pointer* is an object that owns another object and manages that other object through a **pointer**.
>   More precisely, a unique pointer is an object u that stores a **pointer** to a second object p and will dispose of
>   p when u is itself destroyed
>
> [...]
>
> Additionally, *u* can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer *u2*. Upon completion of
>   such a transfer, the following post-conditions hold: [...] *u.p* is equal to `nullptr`

A lambda is not a pointer. A lambda cannot equal `nullptr`.

That said, you're already making your own local struct, why not just use *that* to do the RAII scope guarding itself instead of deferring to `unique_ptr`? That seems like a hack at best, and takes more code to boot. You could instead just do:

```
template< typename lambda >
auto
make_scope_guard(lambda && _lambda)
{
    struct lambda_caller
    {
        lambda _lambda;

        ~lambda_caller()
        {
            _lambda();
        }

    };

    return lambda_caller{std::forward<lambda>(_lambda)};
}
```

If you need to support `release`, you can wrap `_lambda` inside of `boost::optional` so that `lambda_caller` becomes:

```
struct lambda_caller
{
    boost::optional<lambda> _lambda;

    ~lambda_caller()
    {
        if (_lambda) {
            (*_lambda)();
            _lambda = boost::none;
        }
    }

    void release() {
        _lambda = boost::none;
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` allows to perform `release` to cancel the rollback before end-of-scope reaching. `std::unique_ptr` — ready-to-use class with required semantic.

Comment: @Orient Except it doesn't really have the required semantic does it. And do you really need `release()` for this use-case? You could always add it to my `lambda_caller` as well, wrap it in `boost::optional` or some such.

Comment: Really, I don't. But idiom requires `release()` as I know. At least to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: @Orient Easy enough to add. Updated answer.

Comment: @Orient You cannot shove a lambda into a `unique_ptr`, it's still a **pointer**. Added more to clarify.

Comment: Additional text is not relevant to mentioned use case (when *Deleter* have *pointer* member typedef).

Comment: In your case `void release() { lambda_ = boost::none; }` is correct.

Comment: Finally I [found the solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5408278c0a7046fa), but it it imposes dynamic memory allocation, in contrast with your soulution. So your hand-made solution is much more better.